# After using arm64 the apk doesn't work on tablet

Tags: android, arm, apk, 32bit-64bit, google-play-console

My app is currently using only armeabi-v7a and it works properly on phone and tab as well.

However when I upload it to console, it shows the error which I mentioned in the title. I got the solution to that, I added the arm64 and it solved the error.

But if I include the arm64, my app stops working on tablet but it still work on phone.

Any help to get my application to work across all devices would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: does your application contains any other dependencies which also has jni code?

Comment: No thats not the case

Comment: show your application level gradle file config